# How do I get 'T from seq<'T> from a PropertyInfo array

Tags: reflection, f#

I'm using reflection to try and create a datatable based on a record type.  This works fine for a simple record type, but some of my records have sub records (also fine, just made the function recursive), or lists of sub records which is where I have my problem.

As an example, if i have the following types-

```
type ExampleSubType =
    {   PropertyA: string
        PropertyB: int }

type ExampleType =
    {   ID: int
        Name: string
        Example1: ExampleSubType list }
```

I'd like to create a data table with the following columns/types in this order-

```
ID: int
Name: string
PropertyA: string
PropertyB: int
```

I can already do this if I don't have a seq/arr/list anywhere in the types, but the ExampleSubType list part is throwing me off.

Here's the code I've got so far-

```
    let rec private createDataTableColumns record (propertyArr: PropertyInfo []) (dataTable: DataTable)  =
        propertyArr
        |> Seq.iteri(fun i property -> 
            let propType = property.GetType()
            let propValue = propertyArr.[i].GetValue(record)

            match FSharpType.IsRecord(propType), propValue with 
            | true, _ ->
                let subRecordType = propValue.GetType()
                let subPropertyArr = FSharpType.GetRecordFields (subRecordType)
                createDataTableColumns propValue subPropertyArr dataTable

            | false, :? seq<'T> as (_,test) -> 
                let subRecordType = test.GetType()
                let subPropertyArr = FSharpType.GetRecordFields (subRecordType)
                createDataTableColumns propValue subPropertyArr dataTable

            | _, _ ->
                dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType) |> ignore
            )
```

The second match case is the issue.  I can get it to match on that correctly but I'd like `subRecordType` to be `typeof<'T>`.

As it currently is, `test.GetType()` will return `seq<'T>`, not `'T` and I don't know how to extract it from there.

I've also tried let `subRecordType = typeof<'T>`, which works elsewhere in my code, but here it will just return `System.Object`, not whatever type `'T` is and i'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that pattern matching cannot match the shape of a generic type like `seq<_>` and fill in the type argument `'T` for you at runtime. The type argument has to be decided statically during compilation and so (if there are no other constraints), it ends up being compiled as `obj` and, consequently, your code is matching against `seq<obj>`.

The easiest thing is probably to match against non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, which lets you iterate over the elements (which you then get as `obj` values):

```
let matchSeq sq = 
  match box sq with
  | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as e ->
      for v in e do printfn "%A" v
  | _ -> printfn "Not a collection"
```

If you have a sequence `sq`, you can also use reflection to find the type of the generic argument to the `seq<'T>` that it implements and get that as `System.Type`, which should let you find out about the structure of the record:

```
let typ = s.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1")
  .GetGenericArguments().[0]
```

Finally, a more fancy reflection-based trick is to find the type dynamically and use it to invoke your own generic method. That way, you will be able to write code against a concrete implementation of `seq<'T>`:

```
type SeqInvoker = 
  static member Invoke<'T>(items:seq<'T>) = 
    printfn "Type: %s" (typeof<'T>.Name)

let matchSeq s = 
  match box s with
  | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as e ->
      for v in e do 
        printfn "%A" v
      let typ = s.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1")
         .GetGenericArguments().[0]
      typeof<SeqInvoker>.GetMethod("Invoke")
         .MakeGenericMethod(typ).Invoke(null, [| s |])
  | _ -> ()

matchSeq [1;2;3]    // Calls: SeqInvoker.Invoke<int>
matchSeq ["a"; "b"] // Calls: SeqInvoker.Invoke<string>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the detailed explanation.  This is everything I need to get it off the ground.